# Check positions next to an item in a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's say we have a 2D array:

```
array = [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
]
```

and now I want to check for other `0`s next to the position `array[2][2]`. What is the best of achieving this?

Currently, I am doing something like this:

```
if(array[2+1][2] === 0){
    ...
}
if(array[2][2+1] === 0){
   ...
}
...
```

but I am hoping there is a more efficient way of handling this. It requires a lot of repetition and error checks.

Comment: So if we look at the way I arranged the array and my current code, "next to" is positions surrounding the current positions. So [x+1][y], [x][y+1], [x+1][y+1], [x-1][y] and so on. Sorry for my bad wording.

Comment: Just for fun: a mathematical approach: `for(var i =0; i< 4; )
 if(array[x + (i - 2)  % 2][y + (++i - 2) % 2] === 0){      
     /*do your thing */
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check all fields in neighborhood to some field, this is the best way to do this.

Of course you can add some configuration and automation to this by defining neighborhood array:

```
var neighborhoodArray = [[-1,0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]];

var x = 2;
var y = 2;

neighborhoodArray.forEach(function(neigh) {
    if (array[x+neigh[0]][y+neigh[1]] == 0)
        {
            // do sth.
        }
});
```

Thanks to this you can freely define what "next to" means for you

Comment: you probably want to use forEach. `for in` is used to iterate over an object's and it's prototype's properites. Cheers!

Comment: Nice solution :-) Btw, if you want to keep using `for in` you could do `neighbours.west = [0, -1]; neighbours.north = [-1, 0]; ...` :-)

Comment: Hey do you mind telling me what tab is? Thanks for the answer by the way.